# TypeScript error : Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: angular

I'm getting below error while doing ng build --prod but it works fine with ng serve. Please let me know, what can be done to fix this problem.

> typed-list.ts.TypedList.html(18,39): : Cannot invoke an expression
>   whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'EventEmitter' has
>   no compatible call signatures.

I'm copying code snippet for reference as well..

```
@Component({
  selector: 'typed-list',
  template: `
       <div class="container" fxFlex>    

       <div *ngIf="errorMsg.length > 0">
             <p class="error">{{this.errorMsg}}</p>
       </div>

       <form #f="ngForm" name="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">     
          <mat-input-container>
            <input matInput type="text" id="value" name="value" placeholder="Enter value to add" 
                width="auto" [(ngModel)]="value" required>              
          </mat-input-container>         
          <div fxFlex class="container" fxLayoutGap="10px">       
          <div style="overflow-y:auto;height: 250px; width: 400px; border:  1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)">
            <mat-selection-list #list (selectionChange)="selectedValues($event)" >
                <mat-list-option *ngFor="let val of values" [selected]="val.selected" [value]="val">
                    {{val}}
              </mat-list-option>
            </mat-selection-list>            
          </div>

        <div fxFlex fxFlexOrder="1" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayout="column">
              <button type="button" class="md-accent md-raised" mat-raised-button (click)="addVal(value)"> Add </button>
              <button type="button" class="md-primary md-raised" mat-raised-button (click)="removeVal(list)"> Remove </button>
              <button type="button" class="md-primary md-raised" mat-raised-button (click)="clearVal()"> Clear </button>              
        </div> 
        </div>
     </form>   
     </div>

  `,
  styles: [`
    .border-style{
      overflow-y:auto;
      height: 250px; 
      width: 400px; 
      border:  1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    }
    .error{
      color: red;
      border:  1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    }
    `]
})

export class TypedList  implements OnInit{

  values: string[]=[];
  value: string;
  selectedOptions: string[]=[];
  errorMsg : string='';
  @Input() initialVals: string[] = [];
  @Output() selectedValues: EventEmitter<string[]>= new EventEmitter<string[]>();


  ngOnInit(){
    if(!!this.initialVals && this.initialVals.length>0)
         this.values = this.initialVals;
  }

  constructor(){
  }

  commitVal() {
    this.selectedValues.emit(this.values);
  }

  addVal(v: string){
   let isFound:boolean = false;
    if(this.values && this.values.length >0){
       this.values.filter(v1 => {
         if(v1 === v){
           isFound =true;
         }
       });
       if(isFound)
          this.errorMsg = 'Value already exists. Please enter different value';
    }
    if(!isFound) {this.values.push(v); this.errorMsg='';}
    this.selectedValues.emit(this.values);
  }

  onSubmit(f){

  }

  removeVal(v){
    this.selectedOptions = v.selectedOptions.selected.map(item => item.value);
    this.selectedOptions.forEach((v1,index) => {
      this.values.filter((key, index) => {
        if (key === v1) {
          if (index !== -1) {
            this.values.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    this.selectedValues.emit(this.values);
  }

  clearVal(){
    this.values=[];
    this.value='';
    this.selectedOptions=[];
  }


}

Thanks,
Venkatesh.
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot emit the Output() event to same html. The output() will work for only to send data from child to parent tag in html

Thank you

Comment: Thanks Harsha. I have figured out it. Thanks for your answer.